# File included but class not found

Tags: php, wordpress

I know there is many people with this kind of problem, but I haven't found any solution that would be helpful in my case.

I have a simple Wordpress plugin which contains of a main plugin file and two additional files.

```
/myplugin.php
/framework/template/content.php
/framework/pagination/pagination.php
```

The myplugin.php simply echoes the content.php file. The pagination.php is a class with name 'Pagination' - its a github project, you can see it's content here. [Flexible-PHP-Pagination](https://github.com/Modularr/Flexible-PHP-Pagination/blob/master/pagination.php)

The problem occurs when I try to work with this class in the **content.php** file. I can include the class without no problems, but as soon as I want to create object off the Pagination class, it returns fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Pagination' not found in /var/www/.../wp-content/plugins/myplugin/framework/template/content.php:382
```

The way I create the object is this:

```
$nav = new Pagination($max, $total, $page, $maxNum); 
(Note: all variables have proper values)
```

The line 382 is the one where I create $nav variable, not where I include the file (thats on line 3). Any ideas what the problem could be?

**UPDATE (WORKS NOW)**
This is how I imported the file before:

```
include(plugins_url('', __FILE__ ) . '/..../myfile.php');
```

Apperently, it should not be done like that, but **this way instead**:

```
require(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__) . '..../myfile.php'); /* Notice missing slash */
```

Now it works.

Comment: Probably you didn't include that! Use `require` instead, or see the error log.

Comment: seems like you are trying to use the class before it is created - require it first

Comment: I tried to require instead of include but it didnt work. Is this what you guys meant?

Comment: When I use required, it says: Failed opening required 'https://xxx/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/framework/pagination/pagination.php', even though the filepath is correct

Comment: hi vladimir add me on your skype rajkumar.gaur.91@gmail.com

Comment: Hi Rajkumar, its fixed already, but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should load the class using:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'someClassy', 'init' ));

class someClassy {

    public static function init() {
        $class = __CLASS__;
        new $class;
    }

    public function __construct() {
           //construct what you see fit here...
    }

    //etc...
}
```

or

```
add_shortcode( 'baztag', array( My_Plugin::get_instance(), 'foo' ) );
class My_Plugin {

    private $var = 'foo';

    protected static $instance = NULL;

    public static function get_instance() {

        // create an object
        NULL === self::$instance and self::$instance = new self;

        return self::$instance; // return the object
    }

    public function foo() {

        return $this->var; // never echo or print in a shortcode!
    }
}
```